# Why doesnt my Phone vibrate for messages

Tags: notifications, settings, vibration

Currently, when I put my phone into vibrate mode, it only vibrates for calls. It does nothing for texts or emails, however, so I don't know when I've received one. Does anyone know a way to enable vibrating when a text or an email is received? My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9003 superclear LCS.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Messages", click on the menu button, choose "Settings". Then you can choose whether to vibrate or not in the "Notifications".